# I want to link my Google/YouTube account to my company YouTube account

Tags: youtube, google-account, account-management

I have some company videos I would like to upload to my company YouTube account, but Microsoft movie maker won't let me upload them as it says my "Google account is not linked to a YouTube channel. Please visit your YouTube account page to create a YouTube channel or link this account to an existing channel and try again."

Just to clarify:

1. I have a Google/YouTube account
2. The company I work for has one too
3. I can't upload direct to company YouTube account at moment even though I have all passwords

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

In the subject, you say you want to link your personal YouTube account to your company one.   But I cannot see how this will solve your problem.

It sounds to me like you need to:

- Log in to your company YouTube account.
- Create a channel.
- Upload the movies to that channel.